# React Component is invalid in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: internet-explorer, reactjs, internet-explorer-9, webpack, babeljs

I have created a UI component that I have packaged into it's own module. I am implementing it inside of the render function of other components. This works very well except for in IE9. In IE9 I receive the following error:

```
SCRIPT5022: MyCustomComponent.render(): A valid ReactComponent must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object. 
app.029dee66a8362f45fef1.js?029dee66a8362f45fef1, line 11504 character 2
```

Anyone ran into this issue? I've tried logging MyCustomerComponent, and it is the expected object both in Chrome and IE9

```
console.log(typeof(MyCustomComponent));
console.log(MyCustomComponent);
```

both browsers list:

```
LOG: function 

LOG: function MyCustomComponent(props) {
        _classCallCheck(this, MyCustomComponent);
        return _possibleConstructorReturn(this, Object.getPrototypeOf(MyCustomComponent).call(this, props));
      }
```

Here is what my obfuscated component looks like:

```
export default class MyCustomComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={"my-class another-class"}>
        <span className="my-class2"></span>
        <span className="my-class2"></span>
        <span className="my-class2"></span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What does the `render` method in `MyCustomComponent` look like? It's the return statement in render that is causing the problem.

Comment: @dannyjolie I've updated my question with the code of my component

Comment: That seems so weird. Do you import React, or do you have it in the global scope? Maybe it could be related to this https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/5407

Comment: I am importing via import React from 'react'; I did look at that issue for a little bit, but not sure it's related. It might be related to how I'm bundling with webpack.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem was that the application was being built with babel-5 while the component was being built with babel-6. Upgrading the application to be built with babel-6 fixed the problem.